# Mean width and perimeter

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Does anyone know a simple, elementary and self-contained proof of the fact that the mean width of a convex two-dimensional body equals its perimeter divided by $\pi$?

Comment: Planimeter? Gerhard "Shop For Small Ones Online" Paseman, 2018.03.15.

Comment: This is just Cauchy's theorem in integral geometry (or Crofton's formula if you wish). The proof in two dimensions is a simple change of variables. If you want to be more axiomatic, look at the first pages of Klain and Rota where they take this up from the viewpoint of valuations.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Dan Klain's reply:

The only tricky step is that, instead of mean width, consider the functional that measures the number of crossings of a curve with any line in the plane.  In other words, integrate this number of crossings over all lines: over all families of parallel lines and over all directions for those families.  Call this function F(C), where C is the curve.

So F(C) = int_{unit vector u} int_{lines perp to u}  {# crossings  of C with line}  d-line du

If C is a line segment then F(C) is clearly proportional to the length |C| of C (by the same additivity argument as in Barbier's Buffon proof).    Moreover, F is also additive if you glue together two needles at an angle (this is why we use the function F instead of mean projection, which gets funky if you glue at the angle).  So by the same argument and continuity, F(C) is proportional to |C| for all curves C (from a reasonable class).

So we know F(C)  = k|C| for some constant k indep of C.  What is k?

If C happens to be the boundary of a convex region in the plane, then a line crosses C twice or not at all (the tangent cases have measure zero).  Moreover the 2 occurs when the line passes though a point of the projection of C to the perp of a line family.   So from the definition of C (integration over all line families and over the circle of directions) we have
F(C) = 2 * int_circle W_u(C) du
where W_u is the width in direction perp to unit vector u, so that
F(C) = 2 * 2pi * W(C) = 4pi * W(C)
where W(C) is the mean width of the region bounded by the convex curve C.

We now have
k|C| = F(C) =  4pi * W(C)

If we let S be the unit circle, then W_u is always 2 so
2 pi k = k |S| = F(S) = 4pi * W(S) = 8 pi
so k = 4.  This means
|C| = pi * W(C)
when C is a convex curve.

Answer (score 3):

The statement you're looking for is the two-dimensional case of Cauchy's Surface Area Formula, since in two dimensions, the mean width of a convex body is equal to the average area of its projections onto 1-D subspaces. A simple proof can be found in [this arXiv preprint by Tsukerman and Veomett](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05815).

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a complete minimal answer (essentially the same as Dan Klain's answer, but slightly simplified and more direct for the question):

1. By approximation it is enough to prove this for a convex polygon $P$.
2. For each angle $\theta$ the width of $P$ in direction $\theta$ equals the length $l_\theta$ of the projection of $P$ to a line $L_\theta$ of direction $\theta$ (i.e. $\theta$ is the angle of the line with the positive $x$-axis).
   Therefore, the mean width of $P$ equals the average of $l_\theta$ over all $\theta\in [0,\pi]$.
3. Instead of projecting $P$ to $L_\theta$ we can project each side of $P$ to $L_\theta$. Since almost each $P$-projection point arises from two sides, the sum of the lengths of the projections of the sides equals $2l_\theta$, for each $\theta$.
   Therefore, the average of $l_\theta$ over all $\theta$ equals half the sum of the average projection lengths of the sides.
4. It remains to calculate the average projection length of a line segment. Clearly, this depends linearly on its length, say it is $k$ times its length.
   From 1., 2. and 3. it then follows that the mean width of a plane convex body equals $k/2$ times its perimeter.
5. You can calculate $k$ directly for a line segment and get $k=\frac1\pi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta = \frac2\pi$, or more easily you can apply the final result to the disk and obtain that $k/2 = 1/\pi$.

*Remarks:*
a. The core idea of this proof is in step 3: average (over $\theta$) of sum (over sides) equals sum of averages. I think of this as an instance of the general principle of double counting, which has many amazing consequences in combinatorics, analysis (as Fubini's theorem), and other fields.

b. The same proof gives the higher dimensional version of Cauchy's theorem: The average of the 'areas' of the projections of an $n$-dimensional convex body to all $(n-1)$ dimensional hyperplanes equals a constant times its surface 'area'.